# Socket Communication between Delphi and Java

Tags: java, sockets, delphi

I want to create a socket-communication between Delphi6 and Eclipse at localhost. The Delphi-Code seems to work, i can send data from Delphi-Server to Delphi-Client. Now i want to send data from same Delphi-Server to Java-Client. Following code i used from several examples. The connection between Delphi and Java seems established, but at the while-loop (stdIn.readLine()) the programm doesnt work anymore. There is no exception. The programm just stops to work. How can i read data from Delphi-server?

Thanks!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class JavaClientSocketEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10003);
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdIn =
                new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String userInput;
            echoSocket.close();
            while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) { // at this point the programm doesnt work anymore!
                out.println(userInput);
                System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

edit: Delphi-code

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ScktComp, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  CustomRec = record
    Zahl: byte;
end;
TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    sendenButton: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    ClientSocket1: TClientSocket;
    ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sendenButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
      var ErrorCode: Integer);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket;
      ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  senden : boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
text : string;
begin

        text :=  Edit1.Text;
        ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(text);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
        sendenButton.Caption := 'Send';
        senden := false;
        ClientSocket1.Port := 10003;
        ClientSocket1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
        ClientSocket1.Active := true;
        ServerSocket1.Port := 10003;
        ServerSocket1.Active := true;

end;

procedure TForm1.sendenButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  if senden then
   begin
        senden := false;
        sendenButton.Caption := 'Send';
        Timer1.Enabled := false;
   end
  else
   begin
        senden :=true;
        sendenButton.Caption := 'Stopp';
        Timer1.Enabled := true;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
Errorcode := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var  Rec: CustomRec;
begin
     edit2.Text := Socket.ReceiveText;
     rec.Zahl:=StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
     Socket.SendBuf(Rec,sizeof(Rec));
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
Errorcode :=0;
end;

end.
```

The delphi-client starts to send data form first edit-Element (thats the input) periodicly in one-second-interval after I clicked on "sendenButton". The second edit-Element is the output of the received data. It stops to send, after I clicked this button again.

[image]

Comment: Can you complete your question with the Delphi server and elaborate the *"stops to work"* concept? I mean: an exception happens or the `userInput` is immediately `null`?

Comment: `System.in` seems odd to me if you want to output the socket input: `BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

Comment: Theres no exception. In debug-mode at line "userInput = stdIn.readLine()" it seems like the programm is finished. I've also tried other solutions, like this one: http://www.javaproblemstips.com/256592/. But there is the same problem at "String str = in.readLine ();"

Comment: but you are waiting for `System.in`, not for the socket and it seems to me that the socket isn't bound to `System.in`, is it? I don't get the relation between the two, sorry =:-)

Comment: I know what you mean, but this doesnt work either, when i remove "system.in":  Socket echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10003);
      PrintWriter out =
          new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      BufferedReader in =
          new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));

      String userInput;
 //     echoSocket.close();
      while ((userInput = in.readLine()) != null) {
          out.println(userInput);
          System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
      }

Comment: what about this? `InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
        System.out.println("Server response: " + din.readUTF());`

Comment: How do you start the Java Client? From Console? Have you tried typing something in and hit Enter?

Comment: You only catch `IOException`, the application might throw an exception of a different type than the one you are catching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I found a solution for my problem. Thank you very much for your suggestions, fantaghirocco, it helped me to find an answer. It seems I was not understanding the principles of server-client-architecture. I modified your code and now it works fine for me.

Delphi-Code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ScktComp, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  CustomRec = record
    Zahl: Byte;
  end;

TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edit1: TEdit;
    ClientSocket1: TClientSocket;
    ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
    Label1: TLabel;
  procedure ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
    Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
    var ErrorCode: Integer);
  procedure MyServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
    Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  procedure ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket;
    ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
private
public
  { Public-Deklarationen }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  Errorcode := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  rec: CustomRec;
  sInt, reply: string;
  iInt, errorPos: Integer;
begin
  edit1.Text := Socket.ReceiveText;

  sInt := StringReplace(Trim(Edit1.Text), '''', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Val(sInt, iInt, errorPos);

  if errorPos = 0 then begin
    if iInt in [Low(Byte)..High(Byte)] then begin
      rec.Zahl := iInt;
      iInt := iInt +1;
      reply := IntToStr(rec.Zahl);
    end;
  end
  else
    reply := '-1';
    reply := 'reply ' + reply + ' accepted';
  Socket.SendText(reply + #13#10);
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  Errorcode := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientSocket1 := TClientSocket.Create(Self);
  ClientSocket1.OnError := ClientSocket1Error;

  ServerSocket1 := TServerSocket.Create(Self);
  ServerSocket1.OnClientError := ServerSocket1ClientError;
  ServerSocket1.OnClientRead := MyServerSocket1ClientRead;

  ClientSocket1.Port := 10003;
  ClientSocket1.Host := '127.0.0.1';

  ServerSocket1.Port := 10003;
  ServerSocket1.Open;
end;

end.
```

Delphi-Form:

[image]

Java-Code:

```
class TCPClient {
    private static int input;
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Socket echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10003);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    input = 0;
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                input = input +1;
                doTime(echoSocket, input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }
    }, 1000,1000);   
}

private static void doTime(Socket echoSocket, int input) throws IOException {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        //the next 2 lines resume like: if you have to die, die fast
        int value = input;//ensure that input is an Integer
        assert (value >= 0 && value <= 255);// ensure that the Integer is in the Delphi's Byte range
        System.out.println("sending server reply number : " + value);
        out.println(value);
        System.out.println("server replies: " + in.readLine());

    } finally {
        //  echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

1. An issue can be in the `while` loop where you are trying to read and write on an already closed socket.

   ```
   echoSocket.close();
   while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) { // at this point the programm doesnt work anymore!
     out.println(userInput);
     . . .
   ```

   This can be solved moving the `echoSocket.close();` after the loop.
   After that the Java client works; now the issue is in the server.
2. The Delphi client is bound to the server and takes precedence over the Java one.
   To solve this, disable the Delphi client:

   ```
   //ClientSocket1.Active := true;
   ```

   After that the server works.
3. At this point, when you send a number through the console, say `42`, the server raises an exception:

   > Project Project1.exe raised an exception class EConvertError with message ''42
   >   ' is not a valid integer value'.

   The issue happens in the `ServerSocket1ClientRead` mehod with this instruction:

   ```
   rec.Zahl := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
   ```

   Because the string received by the sockect is

   ```
   '42'#$D#$A
   ```

   You may consider to sanitize the text:

   ```
   rec.Zahl := StrToInt(StringReplace(Trim(Edit2.Text), '''', '', [rfReplaceAll]));
   ```
4. When you send the reply to the client, the message terminator `#$D#$A` is missing. The line

   ```
   Socket.SendBuf(Rec, sizeof(Rec));
   ```

   has to be changed like

   ```
   Socket.SendText(IntToStr(rec.Zahl) + #13#10);
   ```

   This solves the blocking client issue.

---

The edited programs follow - I have moved the logic from the `OnActivate` to the `OnCreate` form event:

The Delphi server/client

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ScktComp, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  CustomRec = record
    Zahl: Byte;
  end;

TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    sendenButton: TButton;
  procedure ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
    Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
    var ErrorCode: Integer);
  procedure ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
    Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  procedure ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket;
    ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sendenButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private-Deklarationen }
  ClientSocket1: TClientSocket;
  ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
public
  { Public-Deklarationen }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientSocket1 := TClientSocket.Create(Self);
  ClientSocket1.OnError := ClientSocket1Error;

  ServerSocket1 := TServerSocket.Create(Self);
  ServerSocket1.OnClientError := ServerSocket1ClientError;
  ServerSocket1.OnClientRead := ServerSocket1ClientRead;

  ClientSocket1.Port := 10003;
  ClientSocket1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  //ClientSocket1.Open;

  ServerSocket1.Port := 10003;
  ServerSocket1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.sendenButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sendenButton.Enabled := False;
  ClientSocket1.Open;
  ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit1.Text);
  ClientSocket1.Close;
  sendenButton.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  Errorcode := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  rec: CustomRec;
  sInt, reply: string;
  iInt, iCode: Integer;
begin
  edit2.Text := Socket.ReceiveText;

  sInt := StringReplace(Trim(Edit2.Text), '''', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Val(sInt, iInt, iCode);

  if iCode = 0 then begin
    if iInt in [Low(Byte)..High(Byte)] then begin
      rec.Zahl := iInt;
      reply := IntToStr(rec.Zahl);
    end;
  end
  else
    reply := '-1';

  Socket.SendText(reply + #13#10);
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  Errorcode := 0;
end;

end.
```

The Java client

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Socket echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10003);
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput;

        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {

            //the next 2 lines resume like: if you have to die, die fast
            int value = Integer.parseInt(userInput);//ensure that input is an Integer
            assert (value >= 0 && value <= 255);// ensure that the Integer is in the Delphi's Byte range

            out.println(value);

            System.out.println("server replies: " + in.readLine());
        }
    } finally {
        echoSocket.close();
    }            
}
```

---

Apart from the implementation which uses the `writeLine` and `readLine`, a message can be sent to and read from the server using the `DataOutput.writeUTF` and `DataInput.readUTF` methods:

```
Socket echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10003);
OutputStream os = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(os);
out.writeUTF("Hi, it's me!");//your message to the server
```

```
InputStream in = echoSocket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
System.out.println("Server response: " + din.readUTF());

echoSocket.close();
```

Comment: Same problem as before. The debugger shows this (image): http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150916/ytocuj4u.jpg Seems like the there is a loop

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion fantaghirocco, but it still doesnt work. I don't get any stream in Java. But there is a connection between delphi and java. If I quit the java-program, the delphi-server breaks with an "ESocketError 10053". So I think there is still just a little bug inside the code. I only want to send data from delphi to java without using a textfile ;) can somebody help please?

Comment: I apologize but I've pasted a wrong unit 5 months ago! I've edited the answer again with the right Delphi code. Re-tested, the above works for me. Usage: 1) start the delphi server 2) start the java client 3) wite a number in the java console - send with carriage return

Comment: The delphi client has some minor issues but the point was the communication between the Delphi-server and the Java-client

Comment: Still don't working for me. Got an exception: in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.